# JDBI (not JDBC) Connection Closed - how to handle

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbi

(**This is a JDBI question**, Jarrod Roberson, not just a Postgres question.)

I have a business class calling a DAO method multiple times. After around 15 minutes, that dies with a Connection closed error from Postgres.

```
! Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
! at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:853) ~[hui-populator.jar:0.0.180]
! at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.rollback(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:870) ~[hui-populator.jar:0.0.180]
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
! at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
! at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[hui-populator.jar:0.0.180]
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109) ~[hui-populator.jar:0.0.180]
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80) ~[hui-populator.jar:0.0.180]
! at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.rollback(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.tweak.transactions.LocalTransactionHandler.rollback(LocalTransactionHandler.java:90) ~[hui-populator.jar:0.0.180]
! ... 62 common frames omitted
```

This is the way the Dao class is instantiated:

```
final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getHuiDbDatabase(), "postgres");

    final MyDao myDao = jdbi.onDemand(MyDao.class);
```

A and then this dao has a method annotated with @Transaction, which is called multiple times from the business class.

At some point the connection is closed. What should I do to handle that, so that I can keep calling the @Transaction method?

Comment: XY question? seems the problem isn't how to handle the connection closing, it's why is it closing in the first place.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I strongly suspect it's the DB closing it. But JDBI should handle that, surely.

Comment: `@Transactional` is a Spring annotation, `@Transaction` is a JDBI annotation. In your question you mention `@Transactional` where you should use `@Transaction` instead. Could you please check which annotation you use in your code?

Comment: Sorry, of course it's the correct JDBI annotation.

Comment: The database doesn't close the connection. It can only close its end. You closed your end somewhere.

Comment: JDBI keeps those connections open... So it might be something else dropping it in between.